# establishing a specific graph color based on variables name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm looking for a way to set a specific color to a name when creating graphs (line, bar, and pie charts) using excel 2013.

For Example, I want to graph sales results for Anne, Jim, and Mike but want Anne's portion of the graph to always be colored red, Jim's to be green, and Mike's to be blue regardless of their location in the dataset.

In the example attached the goal is to have 1 color assigned to a Sales Manager regardless of graph.  So instead of 'Anne' having a different color on each graph, all of her results within the graphs would be red, Jim's would be green, Mike's would be blue.

I know in the microcosm of this example you can just manually adjust the "Fill" and "Outline", but looking for an automated way to complete this task for an entire workbook

[image: Dataset example with charts]

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: What do you mean, "Anne's portion of the graph?" Please edit your question to include a screenshot showing the desired result.

Comment: This is probably not hard in VBA. But you’ll get a better response if you improve your question.

Comment: might want to add the VBA tag